# How to take a photo and upload it to the server with Nativecript-camera

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am new to Nativescript Vue development, I am trying to take a photo and send it to the server. My code works fine on Android, but when I run on iOS, errors occur, the image doesn’t even paste onto the page and doesn’t upload to the server.

```
import * as camera from "nativescript-camera";
import * as bghttp from "nativescript-background-http";
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");

takePicture() {
                camera.requestPermissions()
                    .then(() => {
                        camera.takePicture({ width: 300, height: 300, keepAspectRatio: true, saveToGallery:true })
                            .then(imageAsset => {
                                this.img = imageAsset.android;
                            })
                            .catch(e => {
                                console.log('error:', e);
                            });
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log('Error requesting permission');
                    });
            } 
upload() {

                var file =  this.img;
                var url = "https://bocorp.ru/assets/mobileNewOrder.php";
                var name = file.substr(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                // upload configuration
                var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");
                var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
                var request = {
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                        "File-Name": name,
                    },
                    content: JSON.stringify({
                        Title: title
                    }),
                    description: "Uploading " + name
                };
                var task = session.uploadFile(file, request);
```

I understand that another code should be used in "this.img = imageAsset.android;" but I don’t understand how can I get a photo from the Iphone camera. I will be glad to any prompt

Comment: You will have to save the photo to a file using ImageSource module and then use the saved image to upload to server.

Answer (score 1):

We save our images to the device, and then upload later as a multipart upload. You might be able to skip the file saving part, but it does allow us to keep from reading in the entire image for uploading later in our app flow (I guess if you already have the image source for display you could reuse it for upload on the same page).

Hope you find this helpful.

```js
const imageSource = require('tns-core-modules/image-source')
// ...
camera.takePicture(cameraOpts)
  .then(imageAsset => { 
    return imageSource.fromAsset(imageAsset)
  })
  .then(imageSource => {
    let pathDest = '/path/on/device' // you define
    console.log(`Created image source with width=${imageSource.width} height=${imageSource.height} at ${pathDest}`)
    imageSource.saveToFile(pathDest, 'jpg', 50)
    return pathDest // save this to look up later
})
```

Then when we need to upload

```js
const mime = require('mime-types')
import * as bghttp from 'nativescript-background-http'
...
let session = bghttp.session('image-upload')
let request = {
  url: 'https://yourendpoint.com/here',
  method: 'POST',
  androidAutoDeleteAfterUpload: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  }
}
// photoPath is known somehow. We use Vuex, but somehow it makes it to this page
let params = [
  { name: 'photo1', filename: photoPath, mimeType: mime.lookup(photoPath) }
]
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let task = session.multipartUpload(params, request)
   task.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e)
   })
   task.on('complete', res => {
     resolve()
   })
 })
```